# MVC EF save an array of fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I need to save at the same time three fields. Those fields are translations for a key. They are three because I have three languages.

How can I do this kind of saving?

In PHP I could've named those fields like `languages[]` and they were numbered correctly. In code it was easy to make use of this array of fields.

How can I do the same thing ASP.NET with EF + Razor and MVC structure?

After solving this problem, I want to have in the save page all the keys. Let's say I have 13 keys. For this number of keys, I'll have 39 fields to translate in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to add some code to give the basics of your issue. Anyway, put broadly, you can add multiple items to a DbSet on a DbContext and then call SaveChanges on that DbContext.

E.g.

```
var myContext = new MyContext();
myContext.MyTranslations.Add(new Translation{ TranslatedValue="x", Language=lang1});
myContext.MyTranslations.Add(new Translation{ TranslatedValue="x", Language=lang2});
myContext.MyTranslations.Add(new Translation{ TranslatedValue="x", Language=lang3});
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

There are probably a dozen other ways of achieving this, but it should give you the right idea.

Comment: The problem is in the View. There is the problem. I don't know how to name the fields and how to get their results. Also I have to consider the possibility of adding the fourth language.

Comment: If you know the number of translations up front then in the view you can have a loop in C# looping over a piece list of translations that you have added to your model. In the loop you can use Html.TextBoxFor. This will mean the list in the model is auto filled for you from the input fields on form submission.